# Как получить тег Телеграма из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу достать теги из строки,

Строка:
`Здравствуйте, @username. Ваша оплата прошла успешно!`

С ссылками я разобрался `re.findall(r'(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)', text)`, а вот с тегами нет

Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите регулярное выражение для адреса электронной почты.
r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$'
Взято с сайта https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос